# How to get the raw HTML of a node

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to analyze some HTML, but, I don't know how get the raw HTML inside a node.

For example, given:

```html
<tr class="tableX">
  <td align="center">
    <font size="2"><a href="javascript:open('9746')">9746</a></font>
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <font size="2">2012-06-26</font>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When I use this XPath selector:

```ruby
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

nodes = doc.search("//tr[@class='tablebX']")

nodes.each do |node|
   node.text # or node.content
end
```

The results from `node.text` and `node.content` are:

```
9746
2012-06-26
```

I want to get all raw HTML inside the `tr` block, which, in this case, is:

```html
<td align="center">
  <font size="2"><a href="javascript:open('9746')">9746</a></font>
</td>
<td align="center">
  <font size="2">2012-06-26</font>
</td>
```

What's the proper way to do that?

Comment: Node's [`to_html`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNode:to_html) will give you the original HTML.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `node.to_s`, or just `node`:

```
nodes = doc.search("//tr[@class='tablebX']")
nodes.each do |node|
   puts node.to_s
   puts '-'*40
end
```

With additional sanity-check HTML (yours, doubled, with a `tr` of a different class in the middle) I get:

```
<tr class="tableX">
<td align="center">
<font size="2"><a href="javascript:open('9746')">9746</a></font> 
            </td>
            <td align="center"><font size="2">2012-06-26</font></td>
</tr>
----------------------------------------
<tr class="tableX">
<td align="center">
<font size="2"><a href="javascript:open('9746')">9746</a></font> 
            </td>
            <td align="center"><font size="2">2012-06-26</font></td>
</tr>
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add `children.to_html`. Try to do that below:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

nodes = doc.search("//tr[@class='tablebX']")

nodes.each do |node|
   node.children.to_html # or node.content
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct method is `.children`. It returns all the html inside the selected element.

So having this code:

```
<tr class="container">
  <td>value</td>
</tr>
```

And using this process:

```
data = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
data.css("tr.container").children
```

Will return this html:

```
<td>value</td>
```

I guess my answer is too late but that's the exact codes you need.

Comment: Children doesn't return raw HTML, it only returns the NodeSet containing the children of the parent node. The OP wants the raw HTML. `Node#to_html` or its aliases do that.